# What file is causing this URL redirection in AWS?

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, redirect, dns

I'm migrating over a test site to AWS from another company. They've been nothing but unhelpful in giving up the necessary credentials and info to make this a seamless transition.

My test site, now, has everything it needs to be a perfect test site. Looks exactly like the current up and running site, has all the databases, necessary bells and whistles. The only issue is that my AWS public DNS is redirecting to the live server.

I've tried removing all .htaccess files from the EC2 instance and the S3 buckets. I've tried searching for any and all files that would cause this redirect. The live server has nothing on it that would cause this as well.

The IT department of the client only knew that there was some code injection in some file to help redirect every URL the client owns to the same site. I'm at my wits end with non-cooperative dev shops and don't want to spend more time digging through endless files for some few lines of code.

Am I forgetting / missing / overlooking something here? Before I go crazy.

Comment: If it's happening in a .htaccess file then it is related to the web server you have installed on the EC2 server, and really has nothing to do with AWS. If  there are .htaccess files on S3 they aren't being used. Do you have redirect rules configured in S3? If the redirect is happening due to some line of application code returning a redirect response then you are just going to have to search through the code for that. The information you have provided is much too lacking in detail for someone to pinpoint the problem for you.

Comment: Exactly what Mark said. Either fix it at the DNS level or find the redirect in the code.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB thats what I was assuming- just wanted to make sure I was doing all the right things before I freaked out.

Answer (score 0):

1. What do you mean unhelpful giving credentials and information? AWS is a IaaS company, you are responsable for the setup and configuration of your servers. They do offer a paid support plan if you will like to purchase it but it's pretty straightforward to get your access keys when you create an EC2 or RDS instance.
2. Why don't you fix you problem at the dns level? Simply create a subdomain where you will host the temporary test site on the testing server, see if everything works and then change the dns configuration to the live server.

Comment: I think what he meant is that the company who asked him to migrate the site was unhelpful :-)